# Does this double sum converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider:$$\sum_{m,n \in \mathbb{N}_0} \frac{(-m)^n}{n!}.$$

I noticed that $$\sum_{m \in \mathbb{N}_0} \left(\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}  \frac{(-m)^n}{n!} \right)= \sum_{m \in \mathbb{N}_0}   e^{-m} =\frac {e} {e-1} .  $$ but since the series $\sum_{m,n \in \mathbb{N}_0} \frac{(-m)^n}{n!}$ is not absolutely convergent I can't conclude the series converges. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What definition of convergence of a double series do you use?

Comment: By convergence I mean, $\sum_m \sum_n x_{m,n}=\sum_n \sum_m x_{m,n}$

Comment: Then no. Only the nesting with the inner sum over $n$ is convergent, with the inner sum over $m$, the inner series diverges for every $n$.